# pythonaddins.OpenDialog doesn't work properly

Tags: arcpy, python-addin

I am developing a toolbar by the pythonaddins, in regards to define all the input raster files. I wrote the follwoing lines so the user enters how many data he wants to read and accordingly, an input box will be displayed

```
# Import
import arcpy, os,sys, pythonaddins

Folder_Location = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0) # please select a folder to save the project files
ScN=arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1) # please write the number of scenarious to be compared
#-----------------------#
ScN=int(ScN)
for i in range (1,int(ScN)+1):
    MessageD='Select the raster layer of flood depth for scenario No   '#+ str(i)
    Depth_rstr[i]= pythonaddins.OpenDialog(MessageD,False,r'C:\','Select')
```

unfortunatly, the OpenDialog window just display folders without allowing me to double click it to select any file

[image]

hoowever when I write the same lines in python window, it works well

[image]

I notices when I operate this puthonaddins- button, I got this error in the python window

> > > TypeError: GPToolDialog() takes at most 1 argument (2 given)

Could any one advice me, how to solve this problem? I want this could to select files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot see this coding pattern working because you are trying to use the `pythonaddins` module, which is designed for Python AddIns, within a Python Script Tool.

[The pythonaddins module](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/guide-books/python-addins/the-pythonaddins-module.htm) documentation explicitly says right at its start:

> The pythonaddins module can only be used within a Python add-in. It
>   cannot be used in stand-alone scripts or geoprocessing script tools.

I think you should remove the `pythonaddins` module from your code and configure another parameter on the tool dialog of your Python Script tool instead.

Comment: I use these scripts within The pythonaddins.
I have developed a toolbar, and script in the ToolBox
the buttons in the toolbar are just operate the toolbox script using pythonaddins.GPToolDialog(r'D:\.......)

Comment: Are you saying that you have not included a code snippet that works up to where you are stuck?  If that is the case then please review http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4312/writing-code-snippets-to-get-quicker-answers and revise your question.

Comment: Well, I will have a look< thank you
hope I didn;t bother you

Comment: Could you please tell me what parameters in Python Script that read files' paths within a loop instead of pythonaddins.OpenDialog.
Thanks

Comment: I suspect that you should be using a multi-value on that parameter.